# Create Table Not Working in PHP but working in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

When I use:

```
CREATE TABLE test(cardname TEXT, qty TINYINT);
```

in MySQL it works fine, but I've been trying to do the same in PHP with mysqli_query and I keep getting:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE test(cardname TEXT, qty TINYINT);' at line 3
```

Can somebody help please?

EDIT:
Here's some of the code you requested:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("127.2.83.1", "jenerikgs", "", "members");

$username = $_POST['username'];
$q =    "INSERT INTO users
                VALUES('$username', '$password', 20, '../res/logo.png', 0, 0, 0, 'I have not set up a description yet.');
            CREATE TABLE $username(cardname TEXT, qty TINYINT);";
mysqli_query($con, $q);
    echo mysqli_error($con);
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "<br/>";
    echo $q;
```

Comment: can you show your php code?

Comment: You need to post your exact `php` code that is generating the request, as that is where the error is.

Comment: Something tells me your SQL is in quotes.... :P

Comment: $q = "CREATE TABLE test(cardname TEXT, qty TINYINT);";
mysqli_query($con, $q);
        echo mysqli_error($con);
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";
        echo $q;

Comment: @user3102894: As part of the answer.  Code in a comment is not worth the trouble to read.

Comment: A very very very very bad approach.

Comment: So, you are trying to create a table for every username? There must be better solutions...

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know that much about MySQL...I didn't mean to be vague. What part of the code am I missing?

Comment: Read the answer below, mysqli_query doesn't let you perform more than one query in a call to help prevent SQL injection. You need to use multi_query like he has suggested.

Comment: @MillaresRoo yes I am, I don't know any other way I should do this, do you?

Comment: @user3102894 Well, I don't know the entire problem, but maybe with a table 'users', a table 'cards' and a relation 1:N between them will be enough.

Comment: Aside from the ugliness of a table per user (which is easily solved), do you really need TEXT fields for a *name*?

Comment: Well they're card names and I really have no idea how long all of them will be so I just put TEXT just in case

Comment: You'd do well to get a good feel for how long a card's name can be.  TEXT says "up to 65535 characters", which to me feels like way too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this, The `mysqli_multi_query()` function performs one or more queries against the database. The queries are separated with a semicolon.

```
mysqli_multi_query($con,$q);
```

instead of

```
mysqli_query($con, $q);
```